# Proving that a function is continuous on $Z := X \sqcup Y$ if and only if $f_{|X}$ and $f_{|Y}$ are continuous

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I am trying to solve an exercise using the metric that induces the disjoint-union topology. The background is the following metric $\rho$ defined on the metric spaces $X$ and $Y$, with metrics $\rho_X$ and $\rho_Y$, respectively. Here $C$ is a fixed, non-negative constant.
$$\rho(z_1, z_2) = 
\begin{cases}
& \rho_X (z_1, z_2) & \text{ if $z_1, z_2 \in X$} \\ 
& \rho_Y (z_1, z_2) & \text{ if $z_1, z_2 \in Y$} \\ 
& C & \text{ otherwise} 
\end{cases} 
$$
I was able to verify that $\rho$ is a metric.

The exercise I'm trying to solve is below.

> Let $W$ be another metric space. Show that a map of sets $f: Z \to W$ is continuous if and only if $f_{|X}$ and $f_{|Y}$ are continuous.

This fact sounds "obvious" to me, but there must be something I am missing. I believe this is called the "pasting lemma," or is at least very close to it. I recall this being proved using the topological definition, the inverse image of open sets is open. This definition is less natural to me than the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, but I would be interested in anyone has ideas using this alternate definition. Here is my attempt.

> ($\Rightarrow$) suppose $f: Z \to W$ is continuous. Then $f$ is continuous on all of $Z$, so it is continuous on $X \subset Z$ and $Y \subset Z$. Indeed, given $z \in Z$, we have either $z \in X$ or $z \in Y$. Assume WLOG that $z \in X$; the argument is identical, interchanging labels, if $z \in Y$. Then, by continuity of $f$, there exists $\delta > 0$ so that for any $z' \in Z$ and hence any $z' \in X \subset Z$, $\rho(z,z') < \delta$ implies  $\rho_W (f(z), f(z')) < \epsilon$. By definition, $f_{|X}$ is continuous.
>
> ($\Leftarrow$) Suppose $f_{|X}$ and $f_{|Y}$ are continuous. Let $z \in Z$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Without loss of generality, suppose $z \in X$; if $z \in Y$, the argument is similar. By continuity of $f_{|X|}$, there exists $\delta_1 > 0$ such that
> $$
> x' \in X, \rho_X (x, x') < \delta_1 \implies \rho_W (f(x), f(x')) < \epsilon. 
> $$
> Set $\delta := \min(\delta_1, C)$. Then if $z' \in Z$ satisfies $\rho(z,z') < \delta$, we have $z' \in X$ since $\rho(z,z') < \delta = C$. Therefore, $\rho(z,z') = \rho_X (z,z') < \delta \leq \delta_1$, so by the above, it follows that $\rho_W (f(x), f(x')) < \epsilon$, so $f$ is continuous.

Is the proof more involved than this? I would appreciate any feedback on this attempt.

I've added an updated attempt based on the topological definition of continuity.

Suppose that the restrictions $f_{|X}$ and $f_{|Y}$ are continuous. Let $U \subset W$ be open. We must show that $f^{-1} (U) \subset Z$ is open.

A lemma I have access to and was able to prove, using this set $Z$, is:

> $U \subset Z$ is open if and only if $U \cap X$ and $U \cap Y$ are open (in their respective topologies).

By this lemma, it suffices to show that $f^{-1} (U) \cap X$ and $f^{-1} (U) \cap Y$ are open. This should follow from continuity of the restrictions, but there must be a set-theoretic fact that I'm missing. I need to in some way tie this to an element of the codomain.

Comment: What could $C$ possibly be?

Comment: @copper.hat $C$ is just an arbitrary, nonnegative constant. I will edit the post to make that clear.

Comment: For $\rho$ to be a metric, note that you require $C \geq \frac{1}{2}\max\Big(\operatorname{diam}(X,\rho_X), \operatorname{diam}(Y,\rho_Y)\Big)$.  This is more than just $C \geq 0$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I haven't proved this fact, but I believe I've heard it at least once. I'm curious about how one would prove this, if you have a hint.

Comment: @MathNewbie I've deleted my initial comment about the more general pasting lemma since it was only tenuously on-topic.  If you're asking about a hint for that, I'd probably just direct you to a topology book with the proof.  If you're asking for a hint to prove the constraint on $C$ I gave in the comment I've left up, it follows immediately from the triangle inequality.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I believe I see it, though am I correct that this requires that $X$ and $Y$ be nonempty? In order to prove that $\rho_X \leq 2C$, for example, I need to invoke the existence of some element $y \in Y$ and say $\rho_X (x_1, x_2) \leq \rho(x_1, y_1) + \rho(y_1, x_2) = C + C = 2C$.

Comment: Certainly I'm assuming $X,Y$ are non-empty to yield a constraint on $C$ since $C$ only appears in the problem as the distance between a point of $X$ and a point of $Y$.